# Sailing the cryptic seas

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

So, I've built myself a ship. The image shows it from above. (Look, use your imagination, ok?)

With the clues below, try to figure out whether my ship is headed toward the **top right** or toward the **bottom left** corner of the image.

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   2. English city shuns Henry Paisley of musical fame (4)
>   5. Show off expensive top by Prada, moving foot to the left (6)
>   7. Battle site's illegal hunter loses track of singer, gets sad (6)
>   8. Capital's rival top blown up (4 4)
>   9. Our pilot changed fifth course to capital (4 5)
>   11. Take dive out of Galician club to city (5)
>   12. Make sure striking the right number to follow (5)
>   15. Domino recalled by the twelfth Greek, a prominent Turk (7)
>   16. Capital gets rid of capital bird (4)
>   17. Rest of list with messy mush making narrow strip (7)
>   19. Clock parts from French and Swiss components (5)
>   20. Looking back, kitten's father is god of death (3)
>   21. Literary David wants Field's metal (6)
>   22. Make a mistake in most of Asia's predecessor to tango (6)
>   23. Chinese cheers began disintegrating in front of medical centre (6)
>   24. Beggar abandons tavern food item (3)
>   26. Short naval force's star leader takes a step right (3)
>   27. Writer's horizontal heart and vertical feet flipped (4)
>   30. TV network car for hire front to back (3)
>   31. Clarinetist Stiller close to New York (5)
>   32. On top of brontosaurus parts (4)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Director cuts wood for direction (4)
>   2. Well done, Italian car (5)
>   3. Bone research and development switched for Persian king (6)
>   4. Degrade foundation under central idea (6)
>   5. Capital physical activity of agony moving head back (4-2-5)
>   6. Artist spied a library in secret (4)
>   7. Capital's absurd pin-up creator (4-2-6)
>   8. Capital harbour wildly sober in shortest month's limits (4 7)
>   9. Heartless Polish associated with the upper class (4)
>   10. Go around a nutty tree, carve out heart for girl (4)
>   11. A club activity setting (7)
>   13. Close to divine drink with no heart (4)
>   14. Perform in reverse obscured by sundown (4)
>   17. Picture a wizard next to a pillar (6)
>   18. Emergency signal either way (3)
>   21. Messed-up cube with rights to Ilocano language (7)
>   25. Close, unfinished valley (4)
>   28. Santomean preserve's homeless people skinned (3)
>   29. Head down, light brown insect (3)

Comment: Can you check your clue against my answer please. Should the clue say 'back to front' instead of 'front to back'? Thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "Front to back" is correct. You have the right idea but in reverse :)

Comment: But if I move the back of the second thing to the front, I don't get the first thing!!?

Comment: Plot twist: The ship’s moving backwards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Completed grid (by @Deusovi):

> [image]

And as is clearly visible,

> the top left is the PORT side (the nautical term for left), so the ship must be going toward the top right.

**Across**

2. English city shuns Henry Paisley of musical fame (4)

> **BRAD** = English city shuns Henry (BRADFORD - (Henry) FORD) Paisley of musical fame (BRAD (Paisley))

5. Show off expensive top  by Prada, moving foot to the left (6)

> **PARADE** = Show off (PARADE) expensive top (E) by Prada, moving foot to the left (PRADA -> PARAD)

7. Battle site's illegal hunter loses track of singer, gets sad (6)

> **POSADA** = Battle site's (POSADA) illegal hunter loses track of singer (POACHER - CHER = POA), gets sad (PO-SAD-A)

8. Capital's rival top blown up (4 4)

> **PORT VILA** = Capital's (PORT VILA, Vanuatu) rival top blown up (RIVAL TOP -> PORT VILA)

9. Our pilot changed fifth course to capital (4 5)

> **PORT LOUIS** = Our pilot changed (PORT LOUI) fifth course (S) to capital (PORT LOUIS, Mauritius)

11. Take dive out of Galician club to city (5)

> **PORTO** = Take dive out of Galician club (DEPORTIVO (de La Coruña) - DIVE = PORTO) to city (PORTO)

12. Make sure striking the right number to follow (5)

> **ENSUE** = Make sure (ENSURE) striking the right number (ENSURE - R = ENSUE) to follow (ENSUE) (5)

15. Domino recalled by the twelfth Greek, a prominent Turk (7)

> **MUSTAFA** = Domino recalled (FATS (Domino) -> STAF) by the twelfth Greek (MU + STAF), a (A) prominent Turk (MUSTAFA (Kemal Atatürk))

16. Capital gets rid of capital bird (4)

> **ERNE** = Capital (BERNE, capital of Switzerland) gets rid of capital (first letter) = bird (ERNE, a type of seabird often seen in crosswords) - Thanks @Deusovi!

17. Rest of list with messy mush making narrow strip (7)

> **ISTHMUS** = Rest of list (IST) with messy mush (HMUS) making narrow strip (ISTHMUS)

19. Clock parts from French and Swiss components (5)

> **HANDS** = Clock parts (HANDS) from Frenc**h and S**wiss components - Thanks @Deusovi!

br>20. Looking back, kitten's father is god of death (3)

> **MOT** =  Looking back, kitten's father (TOM -> MOT)  is god of death (MOT)

21. Literary David wants Field's metal (6)

> **COPPER** = Literary David ((David) COPPERFIELD) wants Field's metal (COPPERFIELD - FIELD = COPPER)

22. Make a mistake in most of Asia's predecessor to tango (6)

> **SIERRA** = Make a mistake in most of Asia's (SI-ERR-A) predecessor to tango (SIERRA in the NATO alphabet)

23. Chinese cheers began disintegrating in front of medical centre (6)

> **GANBEI** =  Chinese cheers (GANBEI) began disintegrating (GANBE) in front of medical centre ((MED)I(CAL))

24. Beggar abandons tavern food item (3)

> **EGG** =  Beggar abandons tavern (BEGGAR - BAR = EGG) food item (EGG)

26. Short naval force's star leader takes a step right (3)

> **USN** =  Short naval force's (US N(AVY)) star leader takes a step right (SUN -> USN)

27. Writer's horizontal heart and vertical feet flipped (4)

> **ZOLA** =  Writer's (ZOLA) horizontal ((HORI)ZO(NTAL)) heart and vertical feet flipped ((VERTIC(AL) -> LA)

30. TV network car for hire front to back (3)

> **ABC** = TV network (ABC) car for hire front to back (CAB -> ABC) - Thanks @chasly from UK!

31. Clarinetist Stiller close to New York (5)

> **BENNY** = Clarinetist (BENNY (Goodman)) Stiller close to New York (BEN (Stiller) + NY)

32. On top of brontosaurus parts (4)

> **ONTO** = On top of (ONTO) brontosaurus parts (brONTOsaurus)

**Down**

1. Director cuts wood for direction (4)

> **EAST** = Director cuts wood ((Clint) EASTWOOD - WOOD) for direction (EAST)

2. Well done, Italian car (5)

> **BRAVO** = Well done (BRAVO), Italian car ((Fiat) BRAVO)

3. Bone research and development switched for Persian king (6)

> **RADIUS** = Bone (RADIUS) research and development (RAD) switched for Persian king (DARIUS -> RADIUS)

4. Degrade foundation under central idea (6)

> **DEBASE** = Degrade (DEBASE) foundation (BASE) under central idea (I(DE)A + BASE = DEBASE)

5. Capital physical activity of agony moving head back (4-2-5)

> **PORT OF SPAIN** = Capital (PORT OF SPAIN) physical activity (PORT?) of (OF) agony moving head back (PAINS -> SPAIN? Not sure)

6. Artist spied a library in secret (4)

> **DALI** = Artist (DALI) spied a library in secret (SPIE(D A LI)BRARY)

7. Capital's absurd pin-up creator (4-2-6)

> **PORT-AU-PRINCE** = Capital's (PORT AU PRINCE) absurd pin-up creator (PINUPCREATOR -> PORT AU PRINCE)

8. Capital harbour wildly sober in shortest month's limits (4 7)

> **PORT MORESBY** = Capital (PORT MORESBY) harbour (PORT) wildly sober (ORESB) in shortest month's limits (M(A)Y + ORESB = MORESBY))

9. Heartless Polish associated with the upper class (4)

> **POSH** = Heartless Polish (POLISH - LI = POSH) associated with the upper class (POSH)

10. Go around a nutty tree, carve out heart for girl (4)

> **LEAH** = Go around (reverse) a nutty tree (HAZEL), carve out heart (LEZAH - Z = LEAH) for girl (LEAH) - Thanks @Deusovi!

11. A club activity setting (7)

> **PUTTING** = A club activity (PUTTING, as in golf?) setting (PUTTING)

13. Close to divine drink with no heart (4)

> **NEAR** =  Close to (NEAR) divine drink with no heart (NECTAR - CT)

14. Perform in reverse obscured by sundown (4)

> **UNDO** = Perform in reverse (UNDO) obscured by s**undo**wn - Thanks @Deusovi!

17. Picture a wizard next to a pillar (5)

> **IMAGE** =  Picture (IMAGE) a wizard (MAGE) next to a pillar (I looks like a pillar)

18. Emergency signal either way (3)

> **SOS** = Emergency signal (SOS) either way (SOS backwards is SOS) - Thanks @Omega Krypton!

21. Messed-up cube with rights to Ilocano language (7)

> **CEBUANO** = Messed-up cube (CUBE -> CEBU) with rights to Ilocano ((ILOC)ANO) language (CEBUANO)

25. Close, unfinished valley (4)

> **GLEN** = Close, unfinished (GLEN(N) Close) valley (GLEN)

28. Santomean preserve's homeless people skinned (3)

> **OBO** = Santomean preserve's (OBO) Homeless people skinned (HOBO - H) - Thanks @El-Guest!

29. Head down, light brown insect (3)

> **ANT** = 29. Head down, light brown (TAN -> ANT) insect (ANT) (3)

Comment: I've been sniped on all my down answers! Good on you for getting them too :)

Comment: I edited in the rest of the answers and the grid image - hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Deusovi Oh wow, sure I don't mind! Thanks so much :) I'll give you your due credit!

Answer (score 5):

Down

18. Emergency signal either way (3)

> SOS [def: emergency signal; sos is a palindrome, thus either way]

Comment: @CodeBoyCode thanks, but why?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I should answer or add comment to existing answer. Anyway ...

30. TV network car for hire front to back (3)

> cab (Move the last letter of ABC to the front to get a hire car.)

Answer (score 5):

Partial

DOWN

a1. Director cuts wood for direction (4)

> EASTWOOD - WOOD = **EAST**.

n2. Well done, Italian car (5)

> Well done, and Italian car Fiat, **BRAVO**.

m3. Bone research and development switched for Persian king (6)

> Bone (RADIUS) research and development switched (R&D switched) for Persian king **DARIUS**.

l9. Heartless Polish associated with the upper class (4)

> Heartless Polish (POLISH - centre LI) associated with the upper class **POSH**.

o28. Santomean preserve's homeless people skinned (3)

> Homeless people (HOBO) skinned (-H) yields Santomean preserve **OBO**.